# How to convert text input to regex pattern in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

Is there a simple way to convert a `$_POST['var']` to a php regex pattern?

When getting a user input with:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
```

And posting it to php file, the string is accessible with:

```
$_POST['txt1']
```

I have tried:

```
$userPattern = "/^" .  preg_quote($_POST['txt1']) . "$/";
```

But when the user input includes special character like `/`, I get the error "preg_match(): Unknown modifier '$'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close with this line:

```
$userPattern = "/^" .  preg_quote($_POST['txt1']). "$/";
```

But missed an extra parameter which indicates the delimiter that you are using, as explained in http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-quote.php:

```
$userPattern = "/^" . preg_quote($_POST['txt1'], '/') . "$/";
```

The delimiter can be any "any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character" as explained here: http://www.php.net//manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: You're answering yourself in the second-person?

Comment: third person technically

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing... :-)

Comment: But if preg_match() is designed to escape special characters for a regex pattern, why isn't '/' included in the default??

Comment: because the delimeter doen't have to be `/`. It is just the most common.

Comment: No - it is technically second person. 'You' is never used in the third-person because of the narrative nature of the prose. Actually, more technically, this is kind of a line crosser when considering the definitions of person narrative.

Comment: Alternatively if you know a certain delimiter will never be entered, you could use `$userPattern = "~^\Q" . $_POST['txt1'] . "\E$~";`